# Update Cookie in ContainerResponseContext Jersey

Tags: java, cookies, filter, jersey, jax-rs

I am using ContainerResponseFilter to add cookie to each response. Every time a request is made, I want to update the existing cookie. Its expiry time is to be increased.
For this I have tried the following approach:

```
if(firstRequest){
  create a new cookie and add to response ('Set-cookie')
}
else{
  containerResponseContext.getHeaders().remove(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);
  set and update cookie
}
```

But it is not working.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What are you expecting and what is the result?

Comment: @Paul Samsotha
It is adding two cookies. Because after adding the above code I can see two cookies one as request cookie and one as response cookie with each API request. What I want is with each request I receive, I want to update the expiry of the cookie.